# Expanding the square of the absolute value of two vectors

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

In my notes I came across the following expression:

$|\vec r - \vec r'|^2= r^2 +r'^2 - 2r\cdot r' \cos(\theta)$.

How is this possible?

I could understand why, if we had brackets instead of abs values. But as it is I cannot understand how to operate with the square of an abs. value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{r}'$ are elements of a vector space, and not elements of an integral domain, $\left|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'\right|$ does not denote absolute value, but the norm (magnitude) of the vector $\vec{r}-\vec{r}',$ although it actually would be more correct to denote it as $\left|\left|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'\right|\right|$. By definition, $\left|\left|v\right|\right|=\sqrt{v\bullet{v}},$ where $\bullet$ denotes the inner product (the dot product, in this case). So $\left|\left|\vec{r}-\vec{r}'\right|\right|^2=\left(\vec{r}-\vec{r}'\right)\bullet{\left(\vec{r}-\vec{r}'\right)}=\vec{r}\bullet{\vec{r}}-\vec{r}\bullet{\vec{r}'}-\vec{r}'\bullet{\vec{r}}+\vec{r}'\bullet{\vec{r}'}=\left|\left|\vec{r}\right|\right|^2+\left|\left|\vec{r}'\right|\right|^2-2\vec{r}\bullet{\vec{r}'}\cos(\theta).$

This, is actually, the law of cosines in disguise.